# Parsing string variable with jstl

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

Here's my problem.

I need to set up a process, preferably with jstl/jsp, that depending on what a client enters in a URL parameter, a certain URL will be returned, with the same parameters passed on, and opened via javascript pop up function.

Problem I am having, is that the choose statement is not finding one of the parameters unless its one of the beginning parameters.  (Now your thinking, 'huh?')

The list of parameters the client is passing, looks like this...

```
?name=personsname&email=personsemail&tmplatecde=7&legalid=20266998&photoURL=%2Favmedia%2Fweb%2Findex%2F25505893822%2EJPG&agentNumber=047666&FWSType=FR&des=,+CLU%AE,+ChFC%AE&postto=thenetwork.nmfn.com&agentnumber=047666&formname=FWSContactForm2&attr=FRSite
```

Out of that parameter, I only really need the 'formname.'  However if I put the query string in like that, which is what the client is expecting to do, it won't find the formname.  Move the formname parameter to before the 'name' parameter, it works.

At my company we built a custom JSP tag that can simply take that query string and attach it to a specified URL, but to determine that URL I need to check what the formname is equal too.

Does anyone have any ideas of an appropriate way to parse the string to get that formname value?

So far, the code that I have that matters to this issue is

```
<c:choose><c:when test='${param.formname == "FWSContactForm2"}' >
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try shifting the formname parameter to the left and test until it works. Maybe the characters in one of the other parameters is messing things up?

Comment: By the time you get to JSTL and your JSP page, the query string has already been taken apart by the servlet container.  You should debug by figuring out what all the parameters actually are, and that might tell you what part of the URL is syntactically invalid and causing the servlet container to miss the trailing parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work fine. That query string however contains a special character which is been URL-encoded using ISO-8859-1, the `%AE` (the registered mark ®). Maybe the servletcontainer is decoding it using the wrong charset and the one failure followed the other. Remove that `%AE` part and retest. If it works, I'd investigate the URL encoding configuration of the servletcontainer in question. On the other hand, if you have full control over the page which is supposed to send this query string, you could also set the response charset to the same as what the servletcontainer is using. That would break less things.

Comment: Thank you!  With that information I was able to figure out how to resolve the issue by using our custom query string variable and scanning it for the formname parameter.  Easier than messing with the servletcontainer that is already working smoothly.